# Пошаговая игра, обмен данными между клиентом и сервером / PHP

Tags: ajax, php

Решил сделать онлайн игру "Крестики-нолики", хотел бы узнать как правильнее делать обмен данными между клиентом и сервером с точки зрения безопасности?

Т.е. как ход игрока хранить, что бы после перезагрузки страницы нечего не сбилось, в каком виде хранить данные на сервер, в каком на клиенте, каким образом обмениваться, и т.п. подробности.

Вообще на все эти вопросы я сам ответы знаю, но лучше бы узнать мнение опытных.

Делать это буду через ajax и long polling запросы.

С реализацией проблем думаю не должно возникнуть, только нужно хорошая теория, т.к. на его основе собираюсь сделать другую игру.

Comment: Безопасности крестиков-ноликов? _Ну, можно реализовать симметричное шифрование!_

Comment: Достаточно сделать взаимодействие между клиентом и сервером по `https` протоколу.

Answer (score 1):

Храни в бд id игры, каждый ход, id игроков.

Comment: А что ты хотел в такой супер сложной игре?

Comment: При перезагрузке страницы проверять не присутствует ли игрок в незавершённой игре. Если есть выдавать контент согласно последним записям ходов.